# Computing Golden Ratio with SymPy gives complex result

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I'm trying to use SymPy to construct a regular pentagon, and then compute the ratio of a diagonal to an edge.  This is known to be the Golden Ratio, `(1 + sqrt(5)) / 2`, but SymPy isn't computing it correctly.  SymPy's answer, after simplifying by hand, is the product of the Golden Ratio and -i (negative imaginary constant), `-i * (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2`

```
from sympy import simplify
from sympy.geometry import RegularPolygon, Point

sides = 5
polygon = RegularPolygon(Point(0, 0), 1, sides)
diagonal = polygon.vertices[0].distance(polygon.vertices[2])
print("Ratio:", simplify(diagonal/polygon.length))
```

`Ratio: sqrt(sqrt(5) + 5)/sqrt(-sqrt(5) + 5)`

I'm using SymPy because I need to have exact values, and using the pentagon as a test case before moving on to other polygons.  Is there a way to assure that SymPy avoids giving complex solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using nsimplify instead of simplify fixes this.

Comment: You can also see that what was returned is correct, too: 
`expr.equals((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2) -> True`

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using SymPy because I need to have exact values

Sympy is for [symbolic mathematics](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html). If you really need "exact values" to available precision, perhaps [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/) would be more appropriate.

That said, Sympy have tools to test approximations to the golden ratio, and in this case it's the Expr.equals() function:

```py
from sympy import simplify
from sympy.geometry import RegularPolygon, Point
from sympy import GoldenRatio

sides = 5
polygon = RegularPolygon(Point(0, 0), 1, sides)
diagonal = polygon.vertices[0].distance(polygon.vertices[2])
print("Ratio:", simplify(diagonal/polygon.length))
print(simplify(diagonal/polygon.length).equals(GoldenRatio))
```

```
Ratio: sqrt(sqrt(5) + 5)/sqrt(5 - sqrt(5))
True
```

Again, that is symbolic mathematics. No one have the computer power, if there ever will be, neither Python have what it takes to compare irrational numbers precisely.

For example:

```py
>>> 1/3
0.3333333333333333
>>> 1/3 * 3
1.0
>>> 0.3333333333333333 * 3
1.0
```

CPython is just hard defining that [0.9~ == 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...).

So these comparisons won't work:

```py
>>> from sympy import GoldenRatio, simplify
>>> simplify(diagonal/polygon.length) == GoldenRatio
False
>>> import math
>>> GoldenRatio.equals(math.sqrt(math.sqrt(5)+5)/math.sqrt(5-math.sqrt(5)))
False
```

Another example:

```py
>>> from sympy import GoldenRatio, simplify
>>> simplify(diagonal/polygon.length) - GoldenRatio
-GoldenRatio + sqrt(sqrt(5) + 5)/sqrt(5 - sqrt(5))
>>> (simplify(diagonal/polygon.length) - GoldenRatio) == 0
False
>>> (simplify(diagonal/polygon.length) - GoldenRatio).equals(0)
True
```

---

> I'm deeply sorry, I couldn't avoid this: [simplify, man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlsW2hd06R0)